# A multi-developer Git workflow, maintaining a clean history

Tags: git, workflow

Sandofsky [advocates](http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html) being very strict about your 'main' repo's history, keeping it clean without cluttering it with branches and checkpoint commits.

> You should never merge a private branch directly into a public branch with a vanilla merge. First, clean up your branch with tools like reset, rebase, squash merges, and commit amending.
>
> Treat public history as immutable, atomic, and easy to follow. Treat private history as disposable and malleable.

This appeals to me, and I was planning on implementing a workflow where my colleagues each have their own remote repository to push to, and do a pull requests when they've finalized work on a branch and cleaned up the commit history. Subsequently I (the 'integration manager') merge those clean commits into the general development branch.

I guess this approach means that the blessed repo will not have any branches other than [the master and develop branch](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Feature branches will only exist in your local repository -- if collaboration on a branch is needed, this can happen by pushed the branch to the remote repository of one of the collaborating employees.

However, the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html) describes this as a workflow for "*public* small projects". Does this mean it's better to use a different workflow in our case, like pushing the finished branches to the blessed repo instead of to a personal repository?

To be clear: I'm not out to add unecessary complexity or overhead. My goal is to establish a workflow where me and my colleagues can work asynchronously, I can review their work when they're done, and bounce it back with comments or merge it into the code base if all is well.

---

**Edit**: Apparantly the question asked was not clear, so I'll try to summarize it:

Would there be a disadvantage in having my colleagues push their branches directly to our blessed repository (e.g. would it 'pollute' its history in some way)?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question a bit? It's too elaborative. Define "better" workflow. It's always a trade off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of disadvatages:

The blessed repo will rather quickly (depending on how many developers and features) be cluttered with many branches. It's more clean if it only contains e.g. master and develop, than master, develop, featureA, featureB, featureC .. etc. However you can always clean up the repo by deleting them on the remote (git push origin :featureA) but it adds extra clean up work.

Also, when people fetch from the blessed repo their repos will contain remote references to all those branches and when you remove the remote branches, they will have to "git remote prune origin" off and on to clean up references that are no longer valid, which also adds extra work.

Comment: Thank you, this clears it up. :) So, to reverse the question: what would the disadvantages of a setup I orginally described (every dev its own remote repository) be? Somehow I have a feeling this could cause problems, because we're pushing to different targets. Would this somehow make it more cumbersome for them to stay in sync with the main development line?

Comment: Is there a golden mean solution I'm missing?

Comment: Don't think so. Question is if you want people to push to the blessed repo or not, if not they need to push to something else, which means another layer of abstraction. Or you could pull from their repos, but we discussed that yesterday :)

Comment: "A couple of disadvatages" > It does appear to be the way the GitHub team operates, though: http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Comment: Well it's a trade off .. again :) Do you want to have 3204938 branches in your repo so you can see exactly what people are working on, or do you want a clean repo with master and dev branch only? It depends on what you want. Since I know that you are only two developers atm, I'd go for the central repo scenario, it's a trivial setup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **Gitolite**'s ["personal" branches](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/special.html#pers) may suit your needs very well.  It is like having a personal area (a.k.a. namespace) where each developer can (even forcibly) push.  On the contrary, `master` is read-only for all developer but an integrator.

If Alice's `.git/config` contains the following configuration:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@server:project
        push = +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/personal/alice/*
        fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
        fetch = refs/heads/personal/alice/*:refs/remotes/origin/me/*
        fetch = +refs/heads/personal/bob/*:refs/remotes/origin/bob/*
```

then Alice would see

- her branches on the server as `origin/me/branch`, and
- Bob's branches as `origin/bob/branch`.

This way, Alice can:

- work on her branches and pull/push them to the server
- start a new branch off of `master`
- start a new branch off of Bob's branches
- make a backup of her work by simply pushing on the server.

Gitolite can be configured such that Alice cannot write on Bob's personal space and vice-versa:

```
@users = alice bob
@integrators = john
@repos = repo1 repo2

repo @repos
    RW+                         = @integrators
    RW+     personal/USER/      = @users
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why this workflow would not work for you: the emphasis on public may be because for a public project, it's much more important to maintain a clean, immutable history.

Comment: But would having the feature branches in the blessed repo have any negative effect on the development branch's history (as long as they're cleaned before merging)?